# I am learning opencv-python image processing so I wrote this small code but I am getting an error I don't know where I am wrong

Tags: python, opencv3.0

This is my code give below for addition of image but it is giving me error

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

coke = cv2.imread('coca cola.png')
flower = cv2.imread('fall-autumn-red-season.jpg')
img = cv2.addWeighted(coke,0.3,flower,0.7,0)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and i am getting this error

File "D:/Python codes/image addition.py", line 6, in 
img = cv2.addWeighted(coke,0.3,flower,0.7,0)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:659: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::arithm_op'

what should i do to remove the error

Comment: From what I understood, you are trying to apply add to 2 pictures of different sizes. Try to resize one image to the size of the second or both to the same size before applying the `addWeighted()`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion sir it worked for me after your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test since I do not have the images you are using, but try this code and let me know if it works now. I explained the issue in my comment.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

coke = cv2.imread('coca cola.png')
coke1 = cv2.resize(coke,(500, 500), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
flower = cv2.imread('fall-autumn-red-season.jpg')
flower1 = cv2.resize(flower,(500, 500), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
img = cv2.addWeighted(coke1,0.3,flower1,0.7,0)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks sir it is working but you made a very small mistake by writing flower2 instead of flower1 but still i corrected it by my self thanks a lot once again